# Extend Plugin that creates an endpoint for GET request to also accepts POST requests

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I use a plugin called **GiveWP** for creating donation forms. The endpoint to see all the forms and data is `/give-api/v1/forms/`

The plugin has only built an endpoint to **GET** the data of created forms created from the dashboard, but I also need to be able to create new forms from the API via a **POST** request what is currently not possible, so I try to extend the plugin to be able to do this.

First: Create an endpoint to accept **POST** requests for form creation.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'give-api/v1', '/forms/create/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'create_form_endpoint_data',
  ) );
});
```

then use `wp_insert_post()` I used an example from this site. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

```
function create_form_endpoint_data( $postarr, $wp_error = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $defaults = array(
        'post_author'           => $user_id,
        'post_content'          => '',
        'post_content_filtered' => '',
        'post_title'            => '',
        'post_excerpt'          => '',
        'post_status'           => 'draft',
        'post_type'             => 'post',
        'comment_status'        => '',
        'ping_status'           => '',
        'post_password'         => '',
        'to_ping'               => '',
        'pinged'                => '',
        'post_parent'           => 0,
        'menu_order'            => 0,
        'guid'                  => '',
        'import_id'             => 0,
        'context'               => '',
    );

    $postarr = wp_parse_args( $postarr, $defaults );

    unset( $postarr['filter'] );

    $postarr = sanitize_post( $postarr, 'db' );

    // Are we updating or creating?
    $post_ID = 0;
    $update  = false;
    $guid    = $postarr['guid'];

    if ( ! empty( $postarr['ID'] ) ) {
        $update = true;

        // Get the post ID and GUID.
        $post_ID     = $postarr['ID'];
        $post_before = get_post( $post_ID );
        if ( is_null( $post_before ) ) {
            if ( $wp_error ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_post', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ) );
            }
            return 0;
        }

        $guid            = get_post_field( 'guid', $post_ID );
        $previous_status = get_post_field( 'post_status', $post_ID );
    } else {
        $previous_status = 'new';
    }

    $post_type = empty( $postarr['post_type'] ) ? 'post' : $postarr['post_type'];

    $post_title   = $postarr['post_title'];
    $post_content = $postarr['post_content'];
    $post_excerpt = $postarr['post_excerpt'];
    if ( isset( $postarr['post_name'] ) ) {
        $post_name = $postarr['post_name'];
    } elseif ( $update ) {
        // For an update, don't modify the post_name if it wasn't supplied as an argument.
        $post_name = $post_before->post_name;
    }

    $maybe_empty = 'attachment' !== $post_type
        && ! $post_content && ! $post_title && ! $post_excerpt
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'editor' )
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'title' )
        && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'excerpt' );

    /**
     * Filters whether the post should be considered "empty".
     *
     * The post is considered "empty" if both:
     * 1. The post type supports the title, editor, and excerpt fields
     * 2. The title, editor, and excerpt fields are all empty
     *
     * Returning a truthy value to the filter will effectively short-circuit
     * the new post being inserted, returning 0. If $wp_error is true, a WP_Error
     * will be returned instead.
     *
     * @since 3.3.0
     *
     * @param bool  $maybe_empty Whether the post should be considered "empty".
     * @param array $postarr     Array of post data.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', $maybe_empty, $postarr ) ) {
        if ( $wp_error ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'empty_content', __( 'Content, title, and excerpt are empty.' ) );
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    $post_status = empty( $postarr['post_status'] ) ? 'draft' : $postarr['post_status'];
    if ( 'attachment' === $post_type && ! in_array( $post_status, array( 'inherit', 'private', 'trash', 'auto-draft' ), true ) ) {
        $post_status = 'inherit';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $postarr['post_category'] ) ) {
        // Filter out empty terms.
        $post_category = array_filter( $postarr['post_category'] );
    }

    // Make sure we set a valid category.
    if ( empty( $post_category ) || 0 == count( $post_category ) || ! is_array( $post_category ) ) {
        // 'post' requires at least one category.
        if ( 'post' == $post_type && 'auto-draft' != $post_status ) {
            $post_category = array( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
        } else {
            $post_category = array();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't allow contributors to set the post slug for pending review posts.
     *
     * For new posts check the primitive capability, for updates check the meta capability.
     */
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    if ( ! $update && 'pending' === $post_status && ! current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->publish_posts ) ) {
        $post_name = '';
    } elseif ( $update && 'pending' === $post_status && ! current_user_can( 'publish_post', $post_ID ) ) {
        $post_name = '';
    }

    /*
     * Create a valid post name. Drafts and pending posts are allowed to have
     * an empty post name.
     */
    if ( empty( $post_name ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
            $post_name = sanitize_title( $post_title );
        } else {
            $post_name = '';
        }
    } else {
        // On updates, we need to check to see if it's using the old, fixed sanitization context.
        $check_name = sanitize_title( $post_name, '', 'old-save' );
        if ( $update && strtolower( urlencode( $post_name ) ) == $check_name && get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_ID ) == $check_name ) {
            $post_name = $check_name;
        } else { // new post, or slug has changed.
            $post_name = sanitize_title( $post_name );
        }
    }

    /*
     * If the post date is empty (due to having been new or a draft) and status
     * is not 'draft' or 'pending', set date to now.
     */
    if ( empty( $postarr['post_date'] ) || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $postarr['post_date'] ) {
        if ( empty( $postarr['post_date_gmt'] ) || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $postarr['post_date_gmt'] ) {
            $post_date = current_time( 'mysql' );
        } else {
            $post_date = get_date_from_gmt( $postarr['post_date_gmt'] );
        }
    } else {
        $post_date = $postarr['post_date'];
    }

    // Validate the date.
    $mm         = substr( $post_date, 5, 2 );
    $jj         = substr( $post_date, 8, 2 );
    $aa         = substr( $post_date, 0, 4 );
    $valid_date = wp_checkdate( $mm, $jj, $aa, $post_date );
    if ( ! $valid_date ) {
        if ( $wp_error ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'invalid_date', __( 'Invalid date.' ) );
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if ( empty( $postarr['post_date_gmt'] ) || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $postarr['post_date_gmt'] ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $post_status, get_post_stati( array( 'date_floating' => true ) ), true ) ) {
            $post_date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date( $post_date );
        } else {
            $post_date_gmt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
        }
    } else {
        $post_date_gmt = $postarr['post_date_gmt'];
    }

    if ( $update || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post_date ) {
        $post_modified     = current_time( 'mysql' );
        $post_modified_gmt = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );
    } else {
        $post_modified     = $post_date;
        $post_modified_gmt = $post_date_gmt;
    }

    if ( 'attachment' !== $post_type ) {
        $now = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

        if ( 'publish' === $post_status ) {
            if ( strtotime( $post_date_gmt ) - strtotime( $now ) >= MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ) {
                $post_status = 'future';
            }
        } elseif ( 'future' === $post_status ) {
            if ( strtotime( $post_date_gmt ) - strtotime( $now ) < MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ) {
                $post_status = 'publish';
            }
        }
    }

    // Comment status.
    if ( empty( $postarr['comment_status'] ) ) {
        if ( $update ) {
            $comment_status = 'closed';
        } else {
            $comment_status = get_default_comment_status( $post_type );
        }
    } else {
        $comment_status = $postarr['comment_status'];
    }

    // These variables are needed by compact() later.
    $post_content_filtered = $postarr['post_content_filtered'];
    $post_author           = isset( $postarr['post_author'] ) ? $postarr['post_author'] : $user_id;
    $ping_status           = empty( $postarr['ping_status'] ) ? get_default_comment_status( $post_type, 'pingback' ) : $postarr['ping_status'];
    $to_ping               = isset( $postarr['to_ping'] ) ? sanitize_trackback_urls( $postarr['to_ping'] ) : '';
    $pinged                = isset( $postarr['pinged'] ) ? $postarr['pinged'] : '';
    $import_id             = isset( $postarr['import_id'] ) ? $postarr['import_id'] : 0;

    /*
     * The 'wp_insert_post_parent' filter expects all variables to be present.
     * Previously, these variables would have already been extracted
     */
    if ( isset( $postarr['menu_order'] ) ) {
        $menu_order = (int) $postarr['menu_order'];
    } else {
        $menu_order = 0;
    }

    $post_password = isset( $postarr['post_password'] ) ? $postarr['post_password'] : '';
    if ( 'private' == $post_status ) {
        $post_password = '';
    }

    if ( isset( $postarr['post_parent'] ) ) {
        $post_parent = (int) $postarr['post_parent'];
    } else {
        $post_parent = 0;
    }

    $new_postarr = array_merge(
        array(
            'ID' => $post_ID,
        ),
        compact( array_diff( array_keys( $defaults ), array( 'context', 'filter' ) ) )
    );

    /**
     * Filters the post parent -- used to check for and prevent hierarchy loops.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param int   $post_parent Post parent ID.
     * @param int   $post_ID     Post ID.
     * @param array $new_postarr Array of parsed post data.
     * @param array $postarr     Array of sanitized, but otherwise unmodified post data.
     */
    $post_parent = apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_parent', $post_parent, $post_ID, $new_postarr, $postarr );

    /*
     * If the post is being untrashed and it has a desired slug stored in post meta,
     * reassign it.
     */
    if ( 'trash' === $previous_status && 'trash' !== $post_status ) {
        $desired_post_slug = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_desired_post_slug', true );
        if ( $desired_post_slug ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_desired_post_slug' );
            $post_name = $desired_post_slug;
        }
    }

    // If a trashed post has the desired slug, change it and let this post have it.
    if ( 'trash' !== $post_status && $post_name ) {
        /**
         * Filters whether or not to add a `__trashed` suffix to trashed posts that match the name of the updated post.
         *
         * @since 5.4.0
         *
         * @param bool   $add_trashed_suffix Whether to attempt to add the suffix.
         * @param string $post_name          The name of the post being updated.
         * @param int    $post_ID            Post ID.
         */
        $add_trashed_suffix = apply_filters( 'add_trashed_suffix_to_trashed_posts', true, $post_name, $post_ID );

        if ( $add_trashed_suffix ) {
            wp_add_trashed_suffix_to_post_name_for_trashed_posts( $post_name, $post_ID );
        }
    }

    // When trashing an existing post, change its slug to allow non-trashed posts to use it.
    if ( 'trash' === $post_status && 'trash' !== $previous_status && 'new' !== $previous_status ) {
        $post_name = wp_add_trashed_suffix_to_post_name_for_post( $post_ID );
    }

    $post_name = wp_unique_post_slug( $post_name, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent );

    // Don't unslash.
    $post_mime_type = isset( $postarr['post_mime_type'] ) ? $postarr['post_mime_type'] : '';

    // Expected_slashed (everything!).
    $data = compact( 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content', 'post_content_filtered', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'post_type', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping', 'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'menu_order', 'post_mime_type', 'guid' );

    $emoji_fields = array( 'post_title', 'post_content', 'post_excerpt' );

    foreach ( $emoji_fields as $emoji_field ) {
        if ( isset( $data[ $emoji_field ] ) ) {
            $charset = $wpdb->get_col_charset( $wpdb->posts, $emoji_field );
            if ( 'utf8' === $charset ) {
                $data[ $emoji_field ] = wp_encode_emoji( $data[ $emoji_field ] );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( 'attachment' === $post_type ) {
        /**
         * Filters attachment post data before it is updated in or added to the database.
         *
         * @since 3.9.0
         *
         * @param array $data    An array of sanitized attachment post data.
         * @param array $postarr An array of unsanitized attachment post data.
         */
        $data = apply_filters( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', $data, $postarr );
    } else {
        /**
         * Filters slashed post data just before it is inserted into the database.
         *
         * @since 2.7.0
         *
         * @param array $data    An array of slashed post data.
         * @param array $postarr An array of sanitized, but otherwise unmodified post data.
         */
        $data = apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_data', $data, $postarr );
    }
    $data  = wp_unslash( $data );
    $where = array( 'ID' => $post_ID );

    if ( $update ) {
        /**
         * Fires immediately before an existing post is updated in the database.
         *
         * @since 2.5.0
         *
         * @param int   $post_ID Post ID.
         * @param array $data    Array of unslashed post data.
         */
        do_action( 'pre_post_update', $post_ID, $data );
        if ( false === $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $data, $where ) ) {
            if ( $wp_error ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'db_update_error', __( 'Could not update post in the database' ), $wpdb->last_error );
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // If there is a suggested ID, use it if not already present.
        if ( ! empty( $import_id ) ) {
            $import_id = (int) $import_id;
            if ( ! $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $import_id ) ) ) {
                $data['ID'] = $import_id;
            }
        }
        if ( false === $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->posts, $data ) ) {
            if ( $wp_error ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'db_insert_error', __( 'Could not insert post into the database' ), $wpdb->last_error );
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        $post_ID = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;

        // Use the newly generated $post_ID.
        $where = array( 'ID' => $post_ID );
    }

    if ( empty( $data['post_name'] ) && ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $data['post_title'], $post_ID ), $post_ID, $data['post_status'], $post_type, $post_parent );
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $data['post_name'] ), $where );
        clean_post_cache( $post_ID );
    }

    if ( is_object_in_taxonomy( $post_type, 'category' ) ) {
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_category );
    }

    if ( isset( $postarr['tags_input'] ) && is_object_in_taxonomy( $post_type, 'post_tag' ) ) {
        wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $postarr['tags_input'] );
    }

    // New-style support for all custom taxonomies.
    if ( ! empty( $postarr['tax_input'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $postarr['tax_input'] as $taxonomy => $tags ) {
            $taxonomy_obj = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
            if ( ! $taxonomy_obj ) {
                /* translators: %s: Taxonomy name. */
                _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Invalid taxonomy: %s.' ), $taxonomy ), '4.4.0' );
                continue;
            }

            // array = hierarchical, string = non-hierarchical.
            if ( is_array( $tags ) ) {
                $tags = array_filter( $tags );
            }
            if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy_obj->cap->assign_terms ) ) {
                wp_set_post_terms( $post_ID, $tags, $taxonomy );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $postarr['meta_input'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $postarr['meta_input'] as $field => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, $value );
        }
    }

    $current_guid = get_post_field( 'guid', $post_ID );

    // Set GUID.
    if ( ! $update && '' == $current_guid ) {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'guid' => get_permalink( $post_ID ) ), $where );
    }

    if ( 'attachment' === $postarr['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! empty( $postarr['file'] ) ) {
            update_attached_file( $post_ID, $postarr['file'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $postarr['context'] ) ) {
            add_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_context', $postarr['context'], true );
        }
    }

    // Set or remove featured image.
    if ( isset( $postarr['_thumbnail_id'] ) ) {
        $thumbnail_support = current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails', $post_type ) && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'thumbnail' ) || 'revision' === $post_type;
        if ( ! $thumbnail_support && 'attachment' === $post_type && $post_mime_type ) {
            if ( wp_attachment_is( 'audio', $post_ID ) ) {
                $thumbnail_support = post_type_supports( 'attachment:audio', 'thumbnail' ) || current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails', 'attachment:audio' );
            } elseif ( wp_attachment_is( 'video', $post_ID ) ) {
                $thumbnail_support = post_type_supports( 'attachment:video', 'thumbnail' ) || current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails', 'attachment:video' );
            }
        }

        if ( $thumbnail_support ) {
            $thumbnail_id = intval( $postarr['_thumbnail_id'] );
            if ( -1 === $thumbnail_id ) {
                delete_post_thumbnail( $post_ID );
            } else {
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $thumbnail_id );
            }
        }
    }

    clean_post_cache( $post_ID );

    $post = get_post( $post_ID );

    if ( ! empty( $postarr['page_template'] ) ) {
        $post->page_template = $postarr['page_template'];
        $page_templates      = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates( $post );
        if ( 'default' != $postarr['page_template'] && ! isset( $page_templates[ $postarr['page_template'] ] ) ) {
            if ( $wp_error ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_page_template', __( 'Invalid page template.' ) );
            }
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', 'default' );
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', $postarr['page_template'] );
        }
    }

    if ( 'attachment' !== $postarr['post_type'] ) {
        wp_transition_post_status( $data['post_status'], $previous_status, $post );
    } else {
        if ( $update ) {
            /**
             * Fires once an existing attachment has been updated.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             *
             * @param int $post_ID Attachment ID.
             */
            do_action( 'edit_attachment', $post_ID );
            $post_after = get_post( $post_ID );

            /**
             * Fires once an existing attachment has been updated.
             *
             * @since 4.4.0
             *
             * @param int     $post_ID      Post ID.
             * @param WP_Post $post_after   Post object following the update.
             * @param WP_Post $post_before  Post object before the update.
             */
            do_action( 'attachment_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before );
        } else {

            /**
             * Fires once an attachment has been added.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             *
             * @param int $post_ID Attachment ID.
             */
            do_action( 'add_attachment', $post_ID );
        }

        return $post_ID;
    }

    if ( $update ) {
        /**
         * Fires once an existing post has been updated.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$post->post_type`, refers to
         * the post type slug.
         *
         * @since 5.1.0
         *
         * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
         * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
         */
        do_action( "edit_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_ID, $post );

        /**
         * Fires once an existing post has been updated.
         *
         * @since 1.2.0
         *
         * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
         * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
         */
        do_action( 'edit_post', $post_ID, $post );

        $post_after = get_post( $post_ID );

        /**
         * Fires once an existing post has been updated.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param int     $post_ID      Post ID.
         * @param WP_Post $post_after   Post object following the update.
         * @param WP_Post $post_before  Post object before the update.
         */
        do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before );
    }

    /**
     * Fires once a post has been saved.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$post->post_type`, refers to
     * the post type slug.
     *
     * @since 3.7.0
     *
     * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
     * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
     */
    do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_ID, $post, $update );

    /**
     * Fires once a post has been saved.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
     * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
     */
    do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );

    /**
     * Fires once a post has been saved.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
     * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );

    return $post_ID;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work out of the box so do I need in the `$defaults array` under `post_type` to set the `forms` cpt ? Also, how is the array getting data? I know it is from the body which is in the POST request but how do I handle it in the code?

The second problem is the plugin for creating Forms has also a few custom fields like `goal` `pricing` & more, Here how the data for one form looks when I'm GETing it from the server via API.

```
{
            "info": {
                "id": 22,
                "slug": "markus-mueller",
                "title": "Markus Mueller",
                "create_date": "2020-05-08 21:00:43",
                "modified_date": "2020-05-08 21:01:19",
                "status": "publish",
                "author": "1",
                "link": "https://woocommerce-387347-1280601.cloudwaysapps.com/?post_type=give_forms&p=22",
                "content": "",
                "thumbnail": false
            },
            "goal": {
                "amount": "1.00",
                "percentage_completed": 0
            },
            "stats": {
                "total": {
                    "donations": "0",
                    "earnings": "0.00"
                },
                "monthly_average": {
                    "donations": "0",
                    "earnings": "0.00"
                }
            },
            "pricing": {
                "hawai": "1.00"
            }
},
```

So looking at this *GET* response I know now kind of what I need to send with the **POST** request to be able to create a new form via the API but I'm stuck and don't know what is next how to handle data inside code in the array, I hope someone can explain it in detail to me what I'm missing.

Comment: Firstly, the code you've copied for `wp_insert_post()` is not an example, it's the source code for that function. Secondly, the method to create these forms will be specific to the plugin. 3rd-party plugins are off topic here, so you will need to consult the plugin's developer resources.

Comment: I'm not asking here for help with the plugin, I want to create a new endpoint for custom cpt creation via API. Forget the word Plugin when you read the post.

Comment: You do need help with the plugin. The correct way to programmatically create these forms is specific to the plugin.